# Can not change background of code cell style in private stylesheet. Bug?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

I would like to change the background color of the code cell style in my private stylesheet.

I can change the background of the text cell style for example but not the code cell style in my private stylesheet.

I can change the background color of a single code cell in a notebook but I want all code cells to have the same background automatically.

I have been trying to do this via a front-end cell execution as a fix but using the different questions here I did not find a way that works for the code cell style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest, easiest way is to set the background color against the InitializationCell style.

```
Cell[StyleData["InitializationCell"],Background->RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have seen this usage of cell often when trying to find an answer but It is unclear to me what it does or how to use it. If I just evaluate that command seemingly nothing happens.

Comment: @userrandrand, that is a style data cell.  File > New and then Format> Edit stylesheet, paste the above into it, select Yes when the Interpret dialog comes up, and then close the stylesheet notebook.  Inserting a new Code cell in that notebook will now have a blue'ish background.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the background color of the code cell style is tied to that of InitializationCell style. In any case that worked. Thank you again.